# Graphing Software for Teaching

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, math-software

I'm working on building some notes/slides for a high school calculus class I'm teaching. My reference is James Stewart's *Calculus*. I'd like to make my own graphs and I'm wondering if anyone knows what software is used to construct the graphs in this book. I've included a screenshot of one. I'm pretty fluent in $\LaTeX$ and Python, so I was thinking of using TikZ or Matplolib, but I'm wondering if anyone knows exactly what was used to create the graphs in *Calculus*.[image]

Comment: For the last 25 years I have used *Mathematica* exclusively for precisely this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Would say that graphing in Mathematica is a pretty steep learning curve or fairly straightforward? Also do you think that's what most calc books use or do you reckon it's all done in TeX (TikZ)?

Comment: For plotting, *Mathematica* is rather simple.  I've published several books in $\LaTeX$ filled with *Mathematica* figures e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Classification-Pt-1-Richard-Duda/dp/0471056693/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3JAVL18PY8SLB&keywords=duda%2C+hart%2C+%26+stork%2C+pattern+classification%2C+second+edition%2C+wiley&qid=1571169770&sprefix=duda%2C+hart%2Caps%2C209&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider 
the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
which is 
deeply integrated with 
[LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote).

For example, this figure

[image]

was coded as

```
//
// fig6.asy
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";

import graph;

real pagew=7cm,pageh=0.618*pagew;
size(pagew,pageh);

import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(7.5pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

arrowbar arr=Arrow(HookHead,size=2);

real xmin=-3,xmax=25;
real ymin=-3,ymax=19;

xaxis("$x$",xmin,xmax,above=true,arr);
yaxis("$y$",ymin,ymax,above=true,arr);


pair f(real x){
  real a2 = -0.12, a1 = 3.4, a0 = -11;
  return (x, a2*x^2+a1*x+a0);
}

pair fsec(real x){
  real a1 = 0.6, a0 = 3.7;
  return (x,a1*x+a0);
}

guide gfsec=graph(fsec,-1,22);
guide gf=graph(f,5,17);

real penw=0.8bp;

pen fPen=rgb(0.12,0.12,0.12)+penw;
pen secPen= rgb(0,0.68,0.94)+penw;
pen tanPen= rgb(0.93,0,0.55)+penw;
pen mPen=  rgb(0.4,0.78,0.5)+penw;
pen dashPen=gray(0.1)+0.5bp+linetype(new real[]{16,5})+linecap(0); //squarecap =linecap(0)
pen bracePen=darkblue+0.4bp;

real[][] tPQ=intersections(gfsec,gf);

pair P=point(gf,tPQ[0][1]);
pair Q=point(gf,tPQ[1][1]);
pair C=(Q.x,P.y);

pair tanDir=dir(gf,tPQ[0][1]);

guide gtan=(P-8*tanDir)--(P+12*tanDir);

real a=P.x, x=Q.x;

draw(gfsec,secPen);
draw(gf,fPen);
draw(gtan,tanPen);
draw(P--(P.x,0),dashPen);
draw(C--(C.x,0),dashPen);
draw(P--C--Q,mPen);

bracedefaultratio=0.12;
braceinnerangle=radians(88);
braceouterangle=radians(88);

path braceX(pair a, pair b, real offset=0, real amplitude=bracedefaultratio*length(b-a)){
  pair c=a+rotate( 45)*(unit(b-a)*offset);
  pair d=b+rotate(-45)*(unit(a-b)*offset);
  return brace(c,d,amplitude);
}

draw(braceX(C,P,0.35),bracePen);
draw(braceX(Q,C,0.35),bracePen);

dot(P--Q,UnFill);

label("$a$",(a,0),2*plain.S);
label("$x$",(x,0),2*plain.S);
label("$0$",(0,0),2*plain.SW);

label("$P(a,f(a))$",f(a),3*plain.W);
label("$Q(x,f(x))$",f(x),3*plain.E);

label("$x-a$",(P+C)/2,3*plain.S);
label("$f(x)-f(a)$",(Q+C)/2,3*plain.E);
label("$t$",relpoint(gtan,0.85),plain.NW);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in exactly three minutes in *Mathematica*

[image]

And this took 10 seconds:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Take a look at [this](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3527/).

Because someone asked about labelling:

```
Plot[{x, -x^2 + 5}, 
{x, 0, 3}, 
Epilog -> Text[Style["f(x) = g(x)", 16, Italic], {1.8, 2.2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that looks great! Would you be able to post the code so I can get a rough idea?

Comment: Ummm... my code was so simple I deleted it.  Let me post another plot that took 10 seconds to code.

Comment: How do you embed Latexed text/ Label at near the parabola apex, into the graph? Thanks for *Mathematica* code line.

Comment: @Narasimam:  I'll post a simple example with labels in a few minutes.